# Subscribe to a MySQL table so it will alert me on truncate, drop or change

Tags: mysql, flask, mariadb, mysql-python

In short, I seek a way to subscribe to a specific MySQL table so it will alert me whenever it is changed, truncated or doped. I do not want to poll all the time.

I currently work on a system that consists of a database (the data is not provided by me), a flask application and a java-script front-end.

I have a MySQL (MariaDB version 15.1 Distrib 10.0.37-MariaDB, for debian) table that holds some useful information for my java-script application. Basically it holds an polygon that describes an area I work with. This polygon stays constant most of the time.

The problem is that my back-end changes these information once every 3-5 days without announcement. So most of the time the information stays the same until the change. I can not calculate when the change will happen.

At the same time I need these infos every time a user request any kind of information from the front-end. So I need them exactly at the time they change. I can not work with the outdated data.

Currently I always have to look up the polygon in the database, calculate the needed area and then work with it. This causes a lot of unnecessary requests.

I would like to cache these information in the flask layer somehow, hover to do so I would need a way to be notified when the polygon in the database changes.

I already looked into TRIGGERS but they seem to only alter the database itself.
I can not change the back-end, for it is outside my control. Working on outdated infos will create havoc.

Comment: By the way, I already seeked older questions but they all seem to work around this problem.

Comment: There's a reason for only workarounds -- MySQL, for security reasons, does not provide any way to reach out of itself to run a script, send an email, or anything else.

Comment: Ok, why is it more secure to let the user only poll? I mean I can guarantee that no outsider is using that service.